# I am trying to find a file in a directory, but the shell code snippet is not detecting it

Tags: shell

I have a shell script, which has a code block to find a file in the directory but it is not doing the job. I have a file in my directory "changeip.data", in one of the block i am tring to find the file, but it is not detecting the file. I want to check with the condition that the filename starts with "change".

```
cd /home/raymond
file = "changeip.data"
if [[ "$file" == change* ]]; then
    echo "File found..."
else
    echo "File not found..."
fi
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem in your code is `extra space`. make sure there is no space while pointing to file name. refer the following initilization:

```
file="changeip.data"
```

EDIT:

#==================

Full code:

#==================

```
file="changeip.data"
if [[ "$file" == change* ]]; then
   echo "File found..."
else
    echo "File not found..."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that to check is a file exists, you need to use -e but this will only work with complete file names without globbing.

As an alternative, you could try the following:

```
if [[ "$(find -maxdepth 1 -name "zipp*pm2" | wc -l)" -gt "0" ]];
then 
    echo "File Found";
else 
    echo "File Not Found";
fi
```

This will count the output from the find command and if it is greater than 0, will return "File Found", otherwise "File Not Found"